Is there any way in Css of getting a true vertical 100%?
I run into this soo often and just wondering if anything has changed.  I know the web is setup to do scrolling pages, but I only ever build applications - so I always want a space, and potentially scrolling windows within that space.
So basically - I always find myself needing something to fill the available vertical space without creating a scrollbar.
note, (and the key part of this question) - I often don't have any control of (or even. knowledge of) - my parent container
if I use 100% - it just doesn't get any bigger.
If I use 100vh - it's way too big - because the parent container might have margins or paddings or titles or something.
And yes - I know how to use a flexgrid - which would be fine if it were just me against the parent body - but I'm always inside someone else's space that I don't control - and might change over time.
I also know I can do it witjavascript.
So is there any way (with only css) of basically saying "fill any available space up to not needing scrollbars"?
ok - clarifying this:   So lets suppose my html is:
<html>
<body>
  <div class="someone_else_controls_this">
    <div class="mine">
      hi there
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

and the body (something I don't control, because it comes from the container app I'm living in) is something like this:
body {
  padding:40px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}

then if I do this:
.mine
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:lightblue;
}

I get 
and if I do this
.mine
{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:lightblue;
}

I get

the whole point is - I'm a thing being put into lots of different places, so I can't just do like a calc( 100vh - 80px ) or whatever - because it could be in 50 different places all of which might have different margins or padding or whatever else.   The interesting thing is - the horizontal always works, because it's always assumed that we will fill the available width - so all I want is for the vertical to behave like the horizontal

CSS doesn't provide "magical" solutions. It (always) depends on your code, your use case, etc

I think you need to post a code example where it shows why height:100% doesn't work for you.

If you're not in a flexbox or grid context, a height in percent usually requires the parent to have an explicit height.

yep - and that's my question - is it possible do do if you don't have any control over (or knowledge of) the parent?

You can use the box-sizing CSS property to change the way how the element's height is calculated. By default, content-box is used for most elements, which adds up borders and paddings to the final size of the element. It looks like you want to use border-box which includes borders and paddings to the element's size. Note that margins are not accounted for, and that the box-sizing is not inherited.
Demo:


body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.someone_else_controls_this {
  height: 100%;
}

.mine {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
<div class="someone_else_controls_this">
  <div class="mine">
    hi there
  </div>
</div>



When removing box-sizing: border-box; from the above snippet, it's the same case as described.

the point is - I don't own body or someone_else_controls_this.   I can't change them.  they are often different. I'm making something that goes into other things - eg confluence - so I can't set the parent height - I can't set box sizing - I can only control mine and anything under mine
